# Search box that highlight words and divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a search box which highlights the words from different divs, now i want that after the word is highlighted only those divs are shown which has that word, rest divs should hide. The words are being highlighted but am not able to find a way about div.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").on("input.highlight", function() {
    // Determine specified search term
    var searchTerm = $(this).val();
    // Highlight search term inside a specific context
    $(".cd-item").unmark().mark(searchTerm);
  }).trigger("input.highlight").focus();
});
```

```css
    mark {
      background: orange;
      color: black;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="cd-main">
  <header>
    <h1>Want to share anything?!</h1>
  </header>
  <center><form action="/blog/search" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search.." id="search" value="{{search}}">
    <button type="submit">search</button>
  </form></center>
  <br>
  <ul class="cd-gallery">
    {% for post in posts %}
    <li class="cd-item">
      <a href="/blog/ekblog/{{post.key().id()}}">
        <div>
          <h2>Category</h2>
          <p>{{post.subject}}</p>
          <b>View More</b>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
  </ul> <!-- .cd-gallery -->
</main> <!-- .cd-main -->
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML as well, so we can see what you're working with?

Comment: Done...I want to either highlight those divs that has the word or hide the divs which doesn't.

Comment: You'd like to highlight words or highlight `<div>`?

Comment: highlight the word and hide the rest of the div boxes which doesn't have that word.                                                                                                       If there are 5 div boxes then after the search only those div boxes should be shown which has that word (and that word should be highlighted in those div) and the rest div boxes which doesn't have that word should hide.

Comment: class name of all the divs is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My idea:**

For **Highlight Word**:

1. Get `.html()` for each div (assuming they have same className='need-to-highlight')
2. Then use Regex to replace keyword with `<span class="mark">keyword</span>`. **Below regex expression is just one demo, it is not perfect.**. because it doesn't consider some exceptions like child elements have attributes, the attributes contains keywords, you need to customize it by yourself.
3. At below codes, I just simply compare `oldHtml==newHtml`, if ture, hide the div, if false, replace with new Html. The better solution should be use `regex.match()` to check whether match count > 0.

For **Reset Highlight**:

similiar with `Highlight word`, uses regex expression to match `(<span class="mark">)+keyword(</span>)+`, then replace it with keyword. (Tips: Above `Highlight Word` function will cause keyword be wrapped with `<span>` multiple times when click `Highlight Word` multiple times, so uses `(<span>)+` to remove all).

```js
function hgihtwords(keyword){
  $('.need-to-highlight').each(function(index, elem){
    let oldHtml = $(elem).html()
    //console.log(oldHtml.match(new RegExp('(<[a-z1-9]+>.*?)('+keyword+')(.*?<\/[a-z1-9]+>)', 'ig')))
    let newHtml = oldHtml.replace(new RegExp('(<[a-z1-9]+>.*?)('+keyword+')(.*?<\/[a-z1-9]+>)', 'ig'), '$1<span class="mark">$2</span>$3')
    if(oldHtml == newHtml){
      $(elem).hide()
    }
    else{
      $(elem).show().html( newHtml)
    }
    
  })
}

function resetHighlight(){
  $('.need-to-highlight').each(function(index, elem){
    let oldHtml = $(elem).html()
    let newHtml = oldHtml.replace(new RegExp('(<span class="mark">)+(.*?)(</span>)+', 'ig'), '$2')
    $(elem).show().html( newHtml)
  });
}

function showAll(){
  $('.need-to-highlight').show()
}
```

```css
.mark {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search"/>
<button onclick="hgihtwords($('#search').val())">Highlight Words</button>
<button onclick="resetHighlight()">Reset Highlight</button>
<button onclick="showAll()">Show All</button>

<div class="need-to-highlight">
  <h2>A Header Test 1</h2>
  <p>A Description Test 1</p>
  <b>A View More Test 2</b>
</div>
<div class="need-to-highlight">
  <h2>B Header Tes1t1</h2>
  <p>B Description Te1st 1</p>
  <b>B View More Te1st 2</b>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly but instead of putting the word directly can you tell me how to use id or class name of input type box as i want to take word from there.

Comment: @xyz call hgihtword($(‘#you_input_id’).val())  or hightword($(‘.your_input_class’).val())

Comment: I did but its not working, the changes in the function are not being reflected, like in hgihtwords()                                                              let newHtml = oldHtml.replace(new RegExp('(<[a-z1-9]+>.*?)(test)(.*?<\/[a-z1-9]+>)', 'ig'), '$1<span class="mark">$2</span>$3')                                          its still picking 'test' and replacing it with ($(‘#you_input_id’).val())  is not making any difference.

Comment: i did some changes now there is no syntax error but it still not working...its not picking the word from the search box...pls help

Comment: @xyz, just woke up. sorry about that hard code, already fixed it.